# Cannot format partial TextView or Button text in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, string

I'm using Android Studio to create an English language learning app and I want to make a few letters on a button bold but I cannot do it. For example I want the button to read "I like **bas**ketball" as the first syllable in basketball is emphasized when we pronounce the word.

However I cannot get this to work. Here is my strings.xml.

```
<string name="test">I like <b>bas</b>ketball</string>
```

And here is my activity.xml.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/test"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Neither the Button nor the TextView are recognizing the formatting.

I will have over 400 buttons that will require a different set of characters to be bold so I don't want to use spannable strings to code this.

Is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st Approach-**

you string need to be updated to  `<string name="test">I like &lt;b> bas&lt;/b>ketball.</string>` if you are using string from String.xml

but you need to add below code in Activity class to work -

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.test), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
}else{
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.test));
}
```

**2nd Approach-**

Add below code in your `String.xml` file at top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Then add your string in resources -

```
<resources>
    <string name="test"><![CDATA[I like <b> bas</b>ketball]]></string>
</resources>
```

and then in activity class set the `HTML` text like below -

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.test), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
}else{
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.test));
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: The bold tags don't work. Does it work for you if you do it in Android Studio?

Comment: Oh my bad I have updated the code and tested on emulator and it is working please check.

Comment: Ok thanks Dipankar. I appreciate your help. I will try it.

Comment: @RobPaterson I have updated 2 approaches you can try any which looks good for you.